# Breaking the ice on angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a view:

```
    <div id="productList" ng-controller="ProductController">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th width="100%">Item ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in productItems">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td><% item.ID %></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I have a controller:

```
var TestApp = angular.module('TestApp', [], function( $interpolateProvider ) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

TestApp.controller('ProductController', function ( $scope ) {
  ProductRepository.GetPaginatedProducts();
  $scope.productItems = ProductRepository.Model;
});
```

I have a model:

```
var ProductRepository = function ()
{
    return {
        Model: null,

        GetPaginatedProducts: function()
        {
            $.ajax( {
                "url": Test.URL + "/json/products/paginated",
                "dataType": "json",
                "method": "post",
                "success": function( data )
                {
                    ProductRepository.Model = data;
                }
            } );
        },

    }
}
```

When the ajax finished, it updates the ProductRepository.Model data variable which I want the angular controller scope.productItems to work off of.

This is my first time using angular and i think I've missed the point,

Why is the table not updating with the information?

Comment: Dont use jQuery's AJAX in an Angular app, use  the provided `$http` or `$resource` modules.

Comment: It is not updating because the AJAX call is happening outside the angular scope, thus like @tymeJV use the built in functions get get the data in the scope to trigger a digest cycle that will update the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here for sample ajax call http://plnkr.co/edit/5CiC8MWiwo010nwu32he?p=preview

```js
var TestApp = angular.module('plunker', []);

TestApp.factory('ProductRepository', function($http, $q) {
  var Model = [];
  return {
    Model: Model,
    GetPaginatedProducts: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('paginated.json').then(
        //sucess
        function(result) {

          deferred.resolve(result.data)

        }
        //error
        , function() {});

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
})


TestApp.controller('ProductController', function($scope, ProductRepository) {
  $scope.productItems = [];


  ProductRepository.GetPaginatedProducts().then(function(data) {
      //success
      $scope.productItems = data;

    },
    //error
    function() {

      alert("can't get data");


    })



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div id="productList" ng-controller="ProductController">

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th width="100%">Item ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in productItems">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </td>
          <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So a module is a model... ?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 now why ? you can pass ajax call result to controller with promise or you can do that in this way http://plnkr.co/edit/WPJXHceVEaZW48BE2c1h?p=preview using Model

Comment: Sorry, I followed the example you gave me on that plunker site... and got it working. This is beautiful. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As @tymeJV stated in the comment, you should use $http or $resource (or restangular) to perform the data access.  If you are updating values outside of Angular's framework, it has no way of knowing that data has changed. By using something like $http or $resource, Angular is aware when an event has occurred that can change values and automatically checks for updates.

Alternately, you could manually issues an $apply() to essentially handle the digest update manually (ensuring Angular goes through a digest cycle when you've changed values outside of Angular). Take a look at the documentation on $apply() at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope .

However, your best bet is to use the Angular approach in the first place and avoid using jQuery for this.